# Compact operator in $L^2(0,2\pi)$

Tags: analysis, operator-theory, compactness, compact-operators, adjoint-operators

I have to prove that an operator is compact. The operator is $A:L^2[0,2\pi]\to L^2[0,2\pi]$ given by
$$
Au(x)=\cos x\,u(x). 
$$
I have showed that $A$ is bounded and symmetric, I have to prove only the compactness. I had an idea: if I prove that this operator is an integral operator, it's ok, because an integral operator is always compact. Is it true? Is $A$ an integral operator? Thank you!

Comment: I have edited the question. If you want your questions to survive on this site, you have to type them, not include parts as image.

Answer (score 1):

Your operator is not compact. You can easily show that $\sigma(A)=[-1,1]$, which by being uncountable (and/or by having accumulation points other than $0$) prevents $A$ from being compact.

Comment: what is ()? The spectrum? Thanks

Comment: Why this implies that A is not compact?

Comment: Yes, $\sigma(A)$ is the standard notation for the spectrum. The spectrum of a compact operator is either finite or a sequence that converges to zero; in either case, its only possible accumulation point is zero, and it is never uncountable.